# Is there anyway to stop automatic CMake execution in Qt Creator 4.0?

Tags: cmake, qt-creator

I like some of the new CMake features with Qt Creator 4 but it re-runs cmake any time a relevant file changes. Is there any way to stop this? There seems to be no way to tell it to wait if I'm making a batch of changes, or just saving the file to not lose my work.

Comment: would also interest me for qt5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can. It is called Autorun CMake.

In QtCreator just open **Options** -> **Build & Run** and go to tab **CMake**.
Click one of the configured entries. The setting is on the bottom.

I verified this with version 4.1 on Linux.

Comment: CMake is still run once when you launch Qt Creator, is there a way to prevent this ?

Comment: I assume not. QtCreator builts it project file based on the CMake file. Thus at least one run is necessary. Possible every touch of CMake file triggers this on restart of QtCreator.

Answer (score 3):

In version 4.8.1, it looks like this configuration has moved into *Options->Kits* then go to tab *CMake* and (on my machine) under Auto-Detected->System CMake the option appears on the bottom.

[image: qtcreator options menu with auto-CMake disabled]

(This is under Ubuntu 18.04)