# Can I prevent auto-run of CMake at startup of Qt Creator 4?

Tags: cmake, qt-creator

When I start Qt Creator (4.3) and load a session (or a project already configured), CMake is always run at least once. Even if I disabled the autorun of CMake as said in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41598394/6165833). The cache is already there because I manually run CMake when needed.

How can I make Qt Creator to never run CMake automatically ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

Qt Creator 4.3 uses cmake server-mode to get information out of cmake. For that it needs to start cmake, which in turn will need to configure and generate to fetch all the I formation it then passes on to Qt Creator.

The information stored on disk is not sufficient.