# open a Qt cmake project in Qt Creator always re-run cmake

Tags: qt, cmake, qt-creator

I took over a Qt project using cmake on Windows platform; every time I open this project in Qt Creator IDE (by open the top level CMakeLists.txt), Qt Creator always re-run cmake for this project. Then when I run this project, even without changing anything, cmake will re-build the complete project (because cmake is re-run).

How can I avoid such re-build? I use cmake 3.12 and Qt Creator 4.10

p/s: I noticed that there is a similar question [1], but the answer there doesn't help to avoid the re-run.

[1] [Can I prevent auto-run of CMake at startup of Qt Creator 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46159987/can-i-prevent-auto-run-of-cmake-at-startup-of-qt-creator-4)

Comment: This sounds like a project/Cmake config error/problem. Even if CMake re-parses a project, it shouldn't trigger a full rebuild unless some core dependency (source/static lib/etc) was detected as changed. Or perhaps the configuration (CMake settings) is being actually changed somehow between the times you open the project. Could be quite a few things, really. But the point is just because CMake runs, doesn't mean anything will need to be rebuilt.

Comment: @MaximPaperno this project was originally built against cmake 2.8.10 and over there I didn't notice this re-build issue. It only manifests itself when I migrated to cmake 3.12 (without changing CMakeLists.txt files).

Comment: I hear ya, OTOH quite a bit changed in CMake since 2.8 and perhaps there were some 2.x-specific workarounds in the project config, or something...  Or some other backwards incompatibility. I'd certainly check all the CMake config stuff when doing a fairly major version move like that. Of course I also have no idea of the complexity level of your project...  :)